# How to combine two methods for counting items per category?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, refactoring

I have angular 8 application.

And I have two methods for showing how many items for each category. The items comming from the back-end So this are the two categories:

view.html:

```
  <mat-tab>
          <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <mat-icon class="goals">grade</mat-icon>
            <span i18n>Goals</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.Goal) }}
            <a [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id, 'item', 'new', itemTypes.Goal]"
              ><mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
            </a>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { itemType: itemTypes.Goal }"></ng-container>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab>
          <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <mat-icon class="action-steps">list</mat-icon>
            <span i18n>Action steps</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.ActionStep) }}
            <a [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id, 'item', 'new', itemTypes.ActionStep]"
              ><mat-icon class="add_box">add</mat-icon>
            </a>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { itemType: itemTypes.ActionStep }"></ng-container>
        </mat-tab>
```

and this are the two functions responsible for showing the items per category:

```
  dossierItemsCountBy(itemType: DossierItemTypeDto) {
    return this.typeSearchMatches[itemType.toString()] || { total: 0, matches: 0 };
  }

  dossierItemsCountString(itemType: DossierItemTypeDto) {
    const count = this.dossierItemsCountBy(itemType);

    if (this.hasSearchQuery) {
      return `(${count.matches}/${count.total})`;
    } else {
      return `(${count.total})`;
    }
  }
```

But I think the two methods can maybe written in one method. Or maybe that you can make a Pipe of it?

So my question is what is the best approach? And how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to answer the question "what is the best approach?".

Anyway modifying dossierItemsCountString() like this should work:

```
const count = this.typeSearchMatches[itemType.toString()] || { total: 0, matches: 0 };
```

Comment: Yes, oke, thank you. I had that too. But maybe there was a better approach. but oke. I will mark you.

Comment: Don't mark the question as answered if you want a better approach.

Comment: But that is my question. maybe it can;t be better. Maybe this is the solution.